How can I merge or concat mp3 file in an Android app?
My application is music application that
plays various instrument tracks together located in assets
using AssetManager.
And I want to make new mp3 file using these mp3 files
in android studio.
I searched in google and they told me that FFmpeg is the way to
merge or concat mp3 file.
But, people said it costs memory, so My question is there any other ways
merging mp3 files and make new mp3 file with less memory?
If there's no other way, Is there any reference, blogs, githubs that I can get help with?
Thanks in advance.
I searched google and I'm trying to find projects that merges audio,
but most of projects were related to video trim using FFmpeg.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can concatenate mp3s but concatenating the files, although you may hear artifacts. The result will not use less memory than the parts.
